# Dual-boot (Windows/Mac OS X) MacBook Pro HDD replaced with SSD; can no longer boot in Windows on now-external USB HDD

Tags: boot, multi-boot, boot-camp

I recently replaced the HDD on my 17-inch MacBook Pro (Early 2011) with a SSD. I did a clean install of macOS Sierra on the SSD and had no intention of copying the old HDD to the new SSD. I put the old HDD in a USB enclosure.

The HDD was partitioned and bootable in Windows 7 before it was removed from the machine. Now, however, if I plug the HDD in via USB and boot the machine holding the ALT key, the HDD is shown as a boot option, but the Windows partition is not.

Is it possible to boot in Windows from that partition any longer?

I tried booting using the HDD and then choosing Windows from the Startup Disk preferences menu, but when it attempted to boot that way, I got a black screen with a "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key" message.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. I missed that one. I'll close the question.

Comment: Actually, this from Ask Different might be more useful - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49004/install-windows-7-on-external-drive-and-boot-it-from-a-mac